# doctrine persist + persist = insert + insert?

Tags: php, doctrine

i have a simple entity on my project like this:

```
$obj = Entity\ImportResume();
$obj->setStatus(1);

$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();

$obj->setStatus(2);

$em->persist($obj);
$em->flush();
$em->clear();
```

But doctrine performe 2 inserts, i need 1 insert and 1 update.

Obs:

- if i do a var_dump($obj) after first persist my id fileld is filled with database id!
- for me doctrine is ignoring the id on second persist, why?

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discory the cause is: $em->clear();

The clear method clean the state of all entities, and cause de lost of id on Entity Manager.

Solucion:

**Remove $em->clear();**

Thank's TimWolla!

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading the Doctrine Docs right `persist` is only needed on the initial `INSERT`.

This paragraph suggests that simply changing your object and then flushing the storage is enough:

[7.3. Persisting entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities)

> As a result the persistent state of such an entity will subsequently be properly synchronized with the database when EntityManager#flush() is invoked.

and further:

[7.7.2. Synchronizing New and Managed Entities](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#synchronizing-new-and-managed-entities)

> The flush operation applies to a managed entity with the following semantics:
>
> - The entity itself is synchronized to the database using a SQL UPDATE statement, only if at least one persistent field has changed.
> - No SQL updates are executed if the entity did not change.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same objetc , you may do

```
$em->persist($obj);
$obj->setStatus(1);
$obj->setStatus(2);
$em->flush();
```

if are 2 diferent objects

```
$obj1 = Entity\ImportResume();
$obj1->setStatus(1);
$em->persist($obj1);

$obj2 = Entity\ImportResume();
$obj2->setStatus(2);
$em->persist($obj2);

$em->flush();
```

use the 'clear' method only if is necessary restart a process in the same code.